# PHP locale de_DE is returning English locale

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, locale

I am using Apache and php 7 on an Ubuntu System. After installing the german locales and running `locale -a` to check the installed locales, I get `C, C.UTF-8, de_DE, de_DE@euro, de_DE.iso88591, de_DE.iso885915@euro, de_DE.utf8, deutsch, en_US.utf8, german, POSIX`. I also update the locale using `sudo update-locale`. However using the php code

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE');
echo date("F", strtotime("2018-10-10"));
```

It returns me the English "October", not the German "Oktober". I have no idea what I can do... I also restarted the Apache... but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date()` function doesn't listen to the locales - this will be returning values in English only.

From the `date()` documentation,

> To format dates in other languages, you should use the setlocale() and strftime() functions instead of date().

You need to use `strftime()` instead.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'de_DE');
echo strftime("%B", strtotime("2018-10-10"));
```

- [`strftime()` documentation](http://php.net/strftime)